# i am dumping a piped data , but when i try to read using pickle.loads i get an error

Tags: python, stdout, pickle

this code works fine thats piping out

```
    allWriteNodes=nuke.allNodes("Write")
    test = nuke.allNodes()
    for index,each in enumerate(test):
        wrtNodelst.insert(index,each.name())
        print index, each.name()
    sys.stdout.write(pickle.dumps(wrtNodelst))
    quit()
except RuntimeError:
  sys.stderr.write('could not find %s\n' % target_file)
  raise
```

but this line that is going to read in different file causes error:

```
print pickle.loads(process.stdout.read())
```

giving IndexError : list index out of range... any idea what might be causing it and out to read pickled stdout data ?
**The Traceback  error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\RenderUI.py", line 384, in execApp
print pickle.loads(process.stdout.read())
File "D:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 1374, in loads
return Unpickler(file).load()
File "D:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
dispatch[key](self)
File "D:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 1203, in load_setitems
mark = self.marker()
File "D:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 874, in marker
while stack[k] is not mark: k = k-1
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Please include the *full* traceback of your error.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I have included the Traceback  now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
print pickle.load(process.stdout)
```

does this work?

read may not return the whole string.

Comment: do you mean pickle.loads(process.stdout) ?

Comment: no. pickle also has a `load` function that reads from streams such as `stdout` or `open(...)`

Comment: loads is load from string. if you look into `pickle.__file__` you can see that `loads` calls `load` with a StringIO object that can be used like `open` or `sys.stdout`

Comment: if it does not work have a look wether the string is correctly transferred between the processes.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
   print index, each.name()
```

Causes issues, as it is sending debug output to `stdout` before the pickle is sent.

Comment: hmmmm, you could be right, i noticed even if data is recieved by the recieving script it is printing the name of application that i started in terminal mode

Now > Nuke 6.1v3, 32 bit, built Oct 29  (after this is the raw piclkled data i took out coz char limit exceeds)

above "Now > " is in the receiving script